How may I fully backup my system on a 16GB drive, assuming I won't exceed 16GB of used space on the main drive?
How may I fully backup my system on a 16GB drive, assuming I won't exceed 16GB of used space on the main drive?
I downloaded Clonezilla live.
Will this work in making an exact copy of my hard drive using only what is needed onto a 16 Gb pendrive.
I have a 2 Tb hard drive with only about 6 Gb used.

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  Clonezilla live is not a Ubuntu system

One suggestion: you're making this about Clonezilla. As guiverc is implying, technically the software is not running on Ubuntu, so a case could be made that "the question is not about Ubuntu". If you're willing to change your question to "How may I fully backup my system on a 16GB drive, assuming I won't exceed 16GB of used space on the main drive" or something along those lines then the question would become a good fit for the site. Still possibly a duplicate, I haven't looked, but a good fit at least.

@kos I edited the subject and body of the question.

@guiverc I read your links. Using and administering currently supported, official Ubuntu flavors: Ubuntu, Edubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Kylin, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Studio, Xubuntu, Ubuntu Unity and Ubuntu on WSL.It looks like this needs to be edited.

Good! Now a few more questions: do you want an actual image of the drive? Or, in another words, a "picture" of the current state of the drive (stored on a single file) that you can easily use to fully restore the drive to the state it was before the backup bit-by-bit or do you want something like a directory containing all the files, so that you'll be able to browse / restore even single files? If the latter, which directories in the filesystem do you want to backup?

@kos I have a script that copies important files to a 2nd drive. I would like an exact copy of the current state of my hard drive.

What about this? I mean the third dd command (dd + gzip). Mind you, it should be done from a Live USB, with all filesystem unmounted, being very careful when typing the command as an error could result in wiping your data. Also, after a long time that the drive has been in use, "zeroing out" empty space might be needed before the command is run to keep the backup size under 16GB.

(I'm not aware of more user-friendly solutions, however that works, that's what I do if I need to long-term-store the contents of large / semi-empty drives)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
